# Unique Values from Core Data

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data

I have a core data-based app that manages records of auto dealerships.  Each record stores the dealer's address, which is broken into `addressLine1`, `addressLine2`, `city`, `state`, and `zip` components, each stored as a string in the data store.

I would like to present a list of cities with dealerships to the user, so I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to get a list of every *unique* city name that has been entered into the store.  I other words, is it possible to issue some sort of query against all of the dealership records that will return a list of distinct city names?

I would know how to do this easily with a SQL query, but (how) is this done in Core Data?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7):

Core Data have the option to get distinct record. The method of getting unique results using NSArray and NSSets are not recommend.

```
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"<<yourattrib>"]]];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
```

Refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html) and check the answers for [How to fetch distinct values in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785844/how-to-fetch-distinct-values-in-core-data)

Answer (score 5):

You're right, there isn't an "easy" way to do this with Core Data, because Core Data is not a database.  However, it is possible.  Here's the general idea:

1. Fetch all your Dealer objects via an `NSFetchRequest`.  To simplify the query, you can set the fetch request to only fetch the `city` attribute.
2. Execute `NSArray * uniqueCities = [fetchedDealers valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.city"];`

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to ensure a unique set of things is to use NSSet. Once you have the results for a query on city take your NSArray and do

```
NSSet* uniqueResults = [NSSet setWithArray:resultsArray];
```

You can transform the set into another collection class if more convenient or just the object enumerator to do something with all of them. I do not know if this approach or the valueForKeyPath method from Dave DeLong is more efficient.