# How to fetch distinct values in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

So in looking through [Core Data Snippets](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html), I found the following code:

```
...
[request setEntity:entity]; 
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctValues:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"<#Attribute name#>"]];

// Execute the fetch
NSError *error;
id requestedValue = nil; // WTF? This isn't defined or used anywhere
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
     // handle the error
}
```

This is great and seems perfect for what I need...but how does one actually use it? I assume since it's returning dictionaries, I need a key to get at the values - but where's the key defined? Is that the "id requestedValue = nil" line? If so, how does "requestedValue" become the key? Xcode gives me a compiler warning about an unused variable at the "requestedValue" declaration. I feel like I'm missing something here.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

requestedValue is nothing and is obviously not being used (perhaps it was part of some other example that got cut&paste into this example code--who knows). You can just ignore it.

The keys for the dictionary are the same as the attributes you fetched and are defined in your model. So, for example, if you had a person entity with three attributes defined, name, age, phoneNumber, and you requested only name, that would be the only keys with data in your dictionaries. So:

```
[request setEntity:entity]; 
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name"]];

// Execute the fetch
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
     abort();
}
for( NSDictionary* obj in objects ) {
  NSLog(@"Person: %@", [obj objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
// ...
```

So, if you have 5 people in your data store named Bob, Sally, Joe, Freida and Sue, you would see those names print out. If you want to use any of the other attributes (like their age), you would have to add that to the array you set in `setPropertiesToFetch:`.

In most cases, it is probably best to simply retrieve the managed object, however. The object will be faulted so you won't even bring attributes into memory unless you actually access them. Plus, if you want to make changes to the objects, you could and persist them to the store (with managed objects).

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the help. The Core Data Snippets are really useful, but they leave a little to the imagination if you're a new user.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: a "little" to imagination? They leave EVERYTHING to imagination. I feel the urge to spank myself every time my only source of knowledge is the docs written by Apple. Thankfully there's StackOverflow with a lot of killing pros like Jason Coco and others that help us understand the vague cryptographic messages written by Apple in their docs. Apple does great products but their docs sucks infinity squared + 1.

Comment: It looks like setReturnsDistinctValues got changed to setReturnsDistinctResults

Comment: @mishod I think it always was that way, I think I mistyped it ages ago. Either way, I've updated the answer now :)