# Fetching set of NSManagedObjects using attribute

Tags: core-data, distinct, nsfetchrequest

How does one fetch a set of unique managed objects by requesting a specific attribute to be checked.

e.g. A number of people objects and I would like to retrieve all the unique names, one managed object for each unique name, sorted by name.

Answer (score 3):

What about using a request like this

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
request.entity = entity;
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"]];
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptors]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *distinctResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
// Use distinctResults
```

Try and let me know.

P.S. Code is ARC enabled. If you are not using it, call `release` when necessary.

Comment: @Helium3 See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785844/how-to-fetch-distinct-values-in-core-data

Comment: Will this return faulted NSManagedObjects with the associated data readable. E.g. Will other properties of the NSManagedObject be accessible using object.someProperty. Also, how can the propertiesToFetch be applied to only search for the properties in objects that match other properties e.g. age and gender. So, only fetching unique names for people of a specific age and gender?

Comment: @Helium3 If you want to use any of the other attributes, you would have to add that to the array you set in `propertiesToFetch` property.

Comment: That will not return the result I am looking for I think. I would like to pass in 2 values to be checked and from that set, look for unique names and return them. If I pass in the 2 extra properties to the propertiesToFetch method, will that not return distinct values from each property? or will all three properties be evaluated and only distinct ones returned? Should a predicate not be used to fetch objects that match one of two values? How would setting a predicate like this effect the fetch request wanting to fetch by a single property?