# How to store, and fetch object by, an array of integers in core data

Tags: core-data

I've written an application that generates puzzles, which I'd like to store in core data - or in whatever store is most appropriate. I'd also like to search previously stored puzzles to determine if the generated puzzle is a duplicate.

Each puzzle is represented by an array of 50 to 100 digits, and I'd like to be able to store several thousand of them.

It seems like the simplest solution would be to convert the array to a string, simply because I already know how to make a Core Data fetch request with a string. I know its also possible to store binary data in Core Data, but it doesn't seem that Entities can be fetched based on this data?

Are there options I'm missing that would be more appropriate for this kind of task?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your puzzles are stored as digits, so a string representation of the puzzle is very appropriate.

Core Data relationships are an NSSet object which does not allow duplicates, so if you have a core data relationship of `puzzles`, you won't be able to add a duplicate puzzle. However, Core Data defines a duplicate based on the `objectId` property, not the properties of the entity. So in your NSManagedObject subclass for puzzle, you would override `validateForInsert` and `validateForUpdate` methods. In the example below, I assume the puzzle entity has a property named `stringRepresentation` that holds the puzzle string:

```
- (BOOL)validateForUpdate:(NSError **)error
{
    return [self valueIsUnique:self.stringRepresentaion
                   forKey:@"stringRepresentation"
                error:error];
}
- (BOOL)validateForInsert:(NSError **)error
{
    return [self valueIsUnique:self.stringRepresentaion
                forKey:@"stringRepresentation"
                 error:error];
}
- (BOOL)valueIsUnique:(NSString *)value
               forKey:(NSString *)key
                error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSString * entityName = [[self entity] name];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:entityName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSPredicate * filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[c] %@", key, value];
    [request setPredicate:filter];


    NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:error];
    if (array == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving array of values %@", *error);
        array = [NSArray array];
    }

    if (array.count == 1)
    {
        return YES;
    }


    if (error != NULL)
    {
        NSString * propertyName = NSLocalizedString(key, nil);
        NSString * errorString = NSLocalizedString(@"%@ must be unique", nil);
        errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:errorString, propertyName];

        NSDictionary *userInfoDict = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : errorString,
                                        NSValidationObjectErrorKey : self,
                                        NSValidationKeyErrorKey : key};

        *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain
                                            code:NSManagedObjectValidationError
                                        userInfo:userInfoDict];

    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This should be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the NSArray in core data if you use the Transformable data type in core data.

You would add these to NSManagedObject subclass

```
+ (Class)transformedValueClass
{
    return [NSArray class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return YES;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
}
```

Here is a tutorial for this

http://www.lextech.com/2013/01/core-data-transformable-attributes/

Core Data has the ability to fetch distinct objects if you decide to save every puzzle.

[How to fetch distinct values in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785844/how-to-fetch-distinct-values-in-core-data)

Otherwise you need to compare before you save.

Good Luck

Comment: glad to help. Makes using core data much more fun!